# Change CSS of with JQuery from WebForm code-behind

Tags: jquery, css, webforms, juice-ui

I'm trying to change the CSS of an html element from code-behind, but it doesn't seem to be affected. Client-side it works.

I can call other client-side functions from code-behind, but the JQuery CSS only seems to work on client side.

Here's the code I'm calling:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(),
    "script",
    "$('.anibar .ui-progressbar-value').css('background-image', 'url(images/pbar-ani.png)');",
    true);
```

Not sure if this should make a difference - I'm using JuiceUI progressbar - with a regular div it seems to work.

Here's the source for that:

```
<div id="divDialog" style="display: none" class="basic-dialog" title="Uploading..." runat="server">
    <juice:ProgressBar ID="ProgressBar1" runat="server" Value="100" CssClass="anibar" />
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="Please wait." />
    </p>
</div>
```

with the CSS:

```
.anibar
{
    height: 1.6em;
}
.anibar .ui-progressbar-value
{
    background-image: url(Images/pbar-ani.gif);
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the script you're adding with RegisterStartupScript isn't needed, so you can remove that.

There's a functional example of creating an animated progressbar with JuiceUI here: http://juiceui.com/controls/progressbar. It's the second example on the page (oddly enough, labeled Example 1)

It *looks* like you've just copied the code there, which is a good start. The next step for you would be to verify that those css classes are defined correctly on the page in a <style> tag in the <head> or that they're in a css file that is being loaded correctly. Finally, verify that the path to the pbar-ani.gif file is correct, relative to where the css classes are declared.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment below, this would be a more viable solution:

Define two separate css rules.

```
.anibar .ui-progressbar-value { background-image: url(Images/pbar-ani.gif); }
.anibar.loaded .ui-progressbar-value { background-image: url(Images/pbar-ani-other.gif); }
```

Then use jQuery wherever needed to add the 'loaded' (you can change this to whatever) class to the progress bars on the page.

```
$('.anibar').addClass('loaded');
```

Another option would be to remove the 'anibar' class, which would return the control's look back to the original state.

```
$('.anibar').removeClass('anibar');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, what I'm trying to do with the RegisterStartupScript is change the .anibar .ui-progress-value style to a different background image when my code finishes executing. When the page first loads, it's looking good, but I need the background image to change at a certain point (server-side).

Comment: I've updated my original answer to reflect the clarifications you've shared.

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeing any javascript errors in the browser?

Hard to say, but i would check a few things...

1.)Is jquery loaded by the time the start up script gets rendered on page (is '$' defined)?

2.)Is the DOM/JuicUI done rendering when the script gets put on page? If not, can you wrap the script in a jquery document ready?

3.)Is '.ui-progressbar-value' the correct selector and is it an element with content or does it need more css to make the background-image viewable (e.g height,width)?

4.)Do you really need javascript from the codebehind to apply this css rather than a stylesheet?

Hope this may point you to a solution.